# Vertical CSS and Javascript onclick menu clicking on sublevel makes it disappear

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I'm very new to Javascript and pretty new to CSS/HTML as well. I'm trying to create a vertical menu with CSS and javascript. The sublevels should appear on the right of the menu when someone click on the appropriate title. 
I've managed to get it to work with the first sublevel. It appears and disappears when I click it's 'parent'. But whenever I try to click on a title in the sublevel the sublevel closes instead of opens the next sublevel. I know I'm doing something wrong but I can't figure out what it is :( 
I've gathered my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/kyqJ6/  but for some reason it doesn't work there although I've copied it directly.
Here is an example of my js:

```
function dropdown1()
    {
        if(document.getElementById('menu1').style.display=='block'){
            document.getElementById('menu1').style.display='none';
        }
        else{ 
            document.getElementById('menu1').style.display='block';
        }
    };
```

I know I've probably done a lot of stupid things in the code and that there's plenty of things that could be done better, feel free to point those things out but I can live with it (for now) if I can just get help with my question :)
Thanks for reading this and thanks in advance for any consideration/help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your jsfiddle isn't working only because of how you have the script loading. I changed it to be "No wrap - in <head>" instead of onLoad.

Second, the reason this is happening is because of something called `propagation`. Basically imagine if you have two objects, A and B.

```
--------------------
|A                 |
|     --------     |
|    |B       |    |
|    |        |    |
|     --------     |
|                  |
--------------------
```

Now let's say that each of these items has a click event `clickA()` and `clickB()`. In the DOM, all events bubble up the chain of their parent objects. So if you click on A, `clickA()` will fire, **but** if you click on B `clickB()` will fire, followed by `clickA()`. Because B is a child object of A. Here is [a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kyqJ6/1/) that writes to the console when each of these events fire, so you can see what I'm talking about. So your sub-level dropdowns **are** showing up, but then its as if you click on their parent dropdown labels again, hiding everything (if you click the parent dropdown again you will see that your sub-level dropdown did expand).

I have actually written [a blog post](http://goosedotnet.wordpress.com/2013/07/26/stop-event-bubbling-in-html-dom/) in the past that discusses this in much more detail, that you might find helpful. Here is the [jsFiddle referenced in that post](http://jsfiddle.net/GMCae/2/) that has a good visual.

Basically you have two options here:

- Take your sub-level dropdowns out as child elements of their parent dropdowns and instead just position them so that they still appear to be sub-level dropdowns.

> ```
> --------------------  --------
> |A                 | |B       |
> |                  | |        |
> |                  |  --------
> |                  |
> |                  |
> |                  |
> --------------------
> ```

**OR (recommended so you don't have to change too much code)**

- There is a method called `stopPropagation()` that can prevent the event from bubbling. You can add this to each of the click events so that the event stops there. Here is [an updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kyqJ6/2/) that has applied this method to the `dropdown2()` method.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works now and you wrote  the explanation in a way that was easily understandable which I really appreciate! Thankyou so much! :D